# Simplest PowerShell method to get current time expressed as UTC

Tags: powershell, datetime, time, timezone, utc

I have reviewed the post [Creating a DateTime object with a specific UTC DateTime in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487011/creating-a-datetime-object-with-a-specific-utc-datetime-in-powershell), but it does not seem to directly answer the question I am asking:

**What is the most direct method in PowerShell (3.0) to return a sortable string representing "now" as UTC?**

I expected the correct answer to be:

```
Get-Date -Format (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.UniversalSortableDateTimePattern
```

OR

```
Get-Date -Format u
```

but this is not the case.

Example: At 1300 hrs (1pm) on September 1st, 2016 in the Pacific Time Zone during DST, I get the response:

`2016-09-01 13:00:00Z`   (the local time with a `"Z"` appended)

when I was expecting:

`2016-09-01 20:00:00Z`   (correct UTC/GMT time)

So basically, my code is just getting a string representing the "local" time and appending a `"Z"`.

Now, I know I can manipulate to get to that point, but I'm looking for the minimal (simplest, cleanest) way to get here.

Bonus Points (as if they existed):  How do I get that same, sortable result, but displaying with "UTC" and/or "GMT" as the suffix.  Same minimal requirement.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
[DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString('u')
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
[DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString((Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.UniversalSortableDateTimePattern)
```

For the bonus, I think the most straightforward way is just to replace `Z` with `UTC`:

```
[DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString('u').Replace('Z','UTC')
```

I'm assuming you'll always want UTC since that what it seems like from your question. There doesn't appear to be a [format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) to get just the 3 letter time zone.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I use this to match the Node new Date().toISOString() format: [DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ')

Answer (score 2):

If you like to keep using `Get-Date` for better readability in the code...

```
(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, and it also gives the result I want:

```
"[DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString('yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_UTC')"
```

It is showing time in the format **20180108_152407_UTC** 
so you can play with the date/time formatting as you wish basically